# copy range in vba throws runtime error 1004

Tags: excel, runtime-error, vba

I have written a macro that appends first 3 columns from source excel workbooks into a summary sheet.

The code copies the non empty cells in the first 3 columns from the tab "Tabular Data" of Source Workbooks starting with the name "Log*.xls" and appends the same to columns in the summary sheet .All data in summary sheet is appended horizontally.

Now the code works perfectly fine if there is a few 100 rows of data in my source xls (starting with the name "Log*")

However whenever the ""Log*.xsl" files span to thousands, I get a Runtime error when coping data from source file.

Error at line :

```
WorkBk.Worksheets("Tabular Data").Range("A1", Cells(lastRow, "C")).Copy
```

Macro as below:

```
Sub MergeAllWorkbooks()

Dim SummarySheet As Worksheet
Dim FolderPath As String
Dim NRow As Integer
Dim NextCol As Long
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim FileName As String
Dim WorkBk As Workbook


' Create a new workbook and set a variable to the first sheet.
Set SummarySheet = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet).Worksheets(1)

' Modify this folder path to point to the files you want to use.
FolderPath = ThisWorkbook.Path


' Call Dir the first time, pointing it to all Excel files in the folder path.
FileName = Dir(FolderPath & "\" & "Log*.xls")
NRow = 1

' Loop until Dir returns an empty string.
Do While FileName <> ""



    ' Open a workbook in the folder
    Set WorkBk = Workbooks.Open(FolderPath & "\" & FileName)


    ' Find the last non-empty cell in the last row of col C from each Source sheet
    ' Set the source range to be A:1 through C:lastrow

     'lastRow = WorkBk.Worksheets("Tabular Data").Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
     'Set SourceRange = WorkBk.Worksheets("Tabular Data").Range("A1:C" & lastRow).Copy

     lastRow = WorkBk.Worksheets("Tabular Data").Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
     WorkBk.Worksheets("Tabular Data").Range("A1", Cells(lastRow, "C")).Copy


     If NRow = 1 Then
        SummarySheet.Range("A65536").End(xlUp).PasteSpecial
        NRow = NRow + 1

     Else
        NextCol = SummarySheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        SummarySheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1).PasteSpecial
        'SummarySheet.Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Offset(0, 1).PasteSpecial

     End If

    ' Close the source workbook without saving changes.
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    WorkBk.Close savechanges:=False

    ' Use Dir to get the next file name.
    FileName = Dir()


Loop

' Call AutoFit on the destination sheet so that all
' data is readable.
SummarySheet.Columns.AutoFit
SummarySheet.SaveAs (FolderPath & "\" & "Consolidated_Temp_Data.xls")
MsgBox (NRow & " Files Read ")

End Sub
```

Please can anyone assist me on what is the cause and solution to my problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

your code change to like this

```
With WorkBk.Worksheets("Tabular Data")
    .Range("A1", .Cells(lastRow, "C")).Copy
End If
```

Comment: that's true, but give the PO some explanation why, why he should qualify all his `Cells` and `Range` with the `Worksheet` object, etc.

Comment: Cells(lastRow, "C") is not cell of  WorkBk.Worksheets("Tabular Data").  it is activesheet`s cell.  It occurred error.  It should convert  to WorkBk.Worksheets("Tabular Data").Cells(lastRow, "C") .  Use With statement  make this simply.

Comment: Too bad there's no explanation whatsoever, so this answer isn't useful to anybody else